# Android View GONE if language

Tags: android, layout, view

I do not want to display a layout, if the device is set to english united kingdom. What is the best way to do it? Get every time the device language?

Comment: You got something against the UK?! We don't get to see your fancy layouts?! But yes, you can go off the device language.

Comment: Could you explain to use why you would want to do that? I suspect there is a much simpler solution than what you are thinking about.

Comment: You can put your generic layout in `layout` and the layout without the specific part in `layout-en-rGB`. Layouts in `layout-en-rGB` are only chosen if the device is in English from United Kingdom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chech device's language everytime with this code:

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```

Then if not, change view's visibility like this:

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: This code is way incomplete: You get the language, don't store it in a variable  and/or  compare it to anything.

Comment: @Burak you're right, I do not need to store it in a variable to not display the View. Every time I check.

Answer (score 1):

go this way,  GB stands for Great Britain (UK)

```
String locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry(); 

if(locale.equals("GB")) {
//view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//British people are cooool ;)
}else {
//do whatever you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions with `setVisibility` work, but the OP wants to know what's the **best** way to do it as to avoid getting the runtime language every time.

Therefore:

Create a separate layout (the XML file) for the language you want.

For example, create the folder `layout-en-rGB` and in this folder copy the XML file you want to modify, then make the modifications you need.

At runtime, this layout will automatically be loaded every time the language is english-UK.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the best way is to assign a style to the view, then create a default implementation of that style and override the style for the en-rGB locale. If your layout is not trivially simple then this is the best way to do it, because you don't want to override the whole layout file just to override one property.

1) Assign a style to the view you want to hide in your layout file. Here I'm using a TextView:

```
    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/TastyFoodEditText" />
```

2) Define the style in res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="TastyFoodEditText" parent="android:style/Widget.EditText">
    </style>
</resources>
```

3) Override the style for the U.K. locale by creating the file res/values-en-rGB/styles.xml with this content

```
<resources>
    <style name="TastyFoodEditText" parent="android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:visibility">gone</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```